# Why doesn't pandas update a variable's dtype when populating a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed a difference between two pandas version, and was wondering why that was the case / if it was an expected behaviour:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ("Name", "Age"))
df.loc[1] = "Jane", 5
df.loc[2] = "Riley", 24
df.dtypes
```

In my test:

- with Python 3.5 and Pandas 0.18.1, populating the dataframe *does* update the "object" dtype of the `Age` variable to "float64"
- with Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.23.4, populating the dataframe does not update the "object" dtype of the `Age` variable

Why is that? I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation.

**Edit**: I just noticed `df.infer_objects().dtypes`, which might be particularly relevant... Did the automatic "inference" get ditched along the way?

Comment: seems like the newer behaviour makes more sense, so maybe a bug fix?

Comment: why would the newer behaviour make more sense? Safer?

Comment: I think it'll be more helpful if you post this question on pandas Github issues.

Comment: To inference the datatype after each change could be expensive. Maybe the developers skipped that step?

Comment: @DariusMorawiec sounds possible.
@ MohitMotwani will do!